# search Datagridview by using multiple checkedlistbox c#

Tags: c#, mysql, datagridview, checkedlistbox

how can i search data by chekced multiple checkedlistbox when clicking search..?

How can I accomplish filtering data by multiple checkedlistboxes when clicking search?

[image]

For example I want to search data that has penyakit = 'Penyakit B' and placeholder = '07'. So when I click search, it should show one row that matches both of these conditions

Here is what I have so far:

```
        MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(MyConnectionString);
        con.Open();
        try
        {
            MySqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();


            foreach (object itemChecked in chkboxPenyakit.CheckedItems)
            {

                cmd.CommandText = "Select * FROM tb_pasien where Penyakit = '" + itemChecked.ToString() + "'";
            }




            MySqlDataAdapter adap = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            adap.Fill(ds);
            dgvData.DataSource = ds.Tables[0].DefaultView;

        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (con.State == ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                con.Clone();
            }
        }
```

Comment: it's working but only one checkedlistbox which is Penyakit. i want to make it multiple, but i don't know the logic/coding

Comment: You are overwriting the `cmd.CommandText` in your `foreach` loop. Obviously, your query will only have the last `checkbox` from the list.